# Dynamic class name in SLIM used in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim

I am using SLIM with Rails, and would like to optimize one of my views.

I have three alert SCSS classes:

```
alert-notice
alert-success
alert-danger
```

A value: alert-type is passed to the view as a string, with the following possibilities:

```
notice
success
danger
```

I can write a convoluted piece of code, something like this:

```
- if alert-type == 'notice'
    .alert.alert-notice[role="alert"]
      button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
  elsif alert-type == 'success'
    .alert.alert-success[role="alert"]
      button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
  else
     .alert.alert-danger[role="alert"]
       button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
```

But this seems to be very inefficient. Any ideas?

## EDIT:

Something like this, would work:

```
|  <div class="alert alert-
= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger'
| " role="alert"> 
button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
  | ×
```

But this code is kind of ugly, and was wondering if I can use the simplified SLIM syntax: .alert.alert......

Comment: The output for `notice` and `success` are meant to be identical, yes?

Comment: What do you mean identical? If it's alert.alert-notice, then the message will display in a yellow box. If it's alert.alert-sucess, then then the box will be green

Comment: In the code you posted, there is no difference between `notice` and `success`. Or am I misreading it?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll apologize in advance that I don't use slim. But, based on a quick search, it seems like it would be something like

```
div role = "alert" class = "alert alert-#{alert-type}"
  button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
```

It also looks like you should be able to do:

```
.alert[role = "alert" class = "alert-#{alert-type}"]
  button.close[type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"]
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but SLIM offers a syntax that allows me to do: .alert.alert-notice, and not all the extra syntax, and was wondering if there's a way to do using the simplified syntax. Please see edits to my question for an example.

Comment: Welp, nine lines down to two with no embedded logic and just some simple string interpolation seems pretty straightforward to me. The string interpolation seems consistent with the [Attributes](https://github.com/slim-template/slim#attributes) section of the slim home page. I'm not sure how much cleaner you're imagining this could get, but I'll look forward to better answers from others.